# h2o, how to get internal trees when binomial_double_trees is True in python

Tags: python-3.x, random-forest, decision-tree, h2o, h2o.ai

I'm using the `h2o` package in Python.

When `binomial_double_trees == True`, I want to know information about internal all trees for a class.

This is my parameter:

```py
h2o_rfe = H2ORandomForestEstimator(ntrees=3, max_depth=12, min_rows=10, binomial_double_trees=True)
```

If I use:

```
h2o_rfe.predict_leaf_node_assignment()
```

I can see that each tree is classified according to a separate tree and is also in `h2o` flow web page.

However, if I use:

```py
list_of_trees = [H2OTree(model=h2o_rfe, tree_number=t, tree_class=None) for t in range(h2o_rfe.params['ntrees']['actual'])]'
```

I can't know the information of each internal tree according to the class.

Also I tried to set the `tree_class` (domain is 0,1):

```
list_of_trees = [H2OTree(model=h2o_rfe, tree_number=t, tree_class="0") for t in range(h2o_rfe.params['ntrees']['actual'])]'
```

When `tree_class` is `'0'`, it is okay:

```
list_of_trees = [H2OTree(model=h2o_rfe, tree_number=t, tree_class="1") for t in range(h2o_rfe.params['ntrees']['actual'])]'
```

But when `tree_class` is `'1'`, this error occurs:

> Error: For binomial, only one tree class has been built per each iteration: 0

How to check the internal trees?